# Database connection from one server to another server

Tags: php, mysql, database

Is it possible to connect to a database lying on different server through another server ?

For example :-

I want to access the users table of `www.abc.com`  from `www.xqz.com`, both are on different server.

Can you give me any ideas ?
will really appreciate if provide me the `php query` to connect.
Thanks.

Comment: Can these servers physically talk to each other in any way?

Comment: "through another server" your mean 'anouther mysql server' or just server?

Comment: sorry I am new to this, both the websites have a different shared hosting providers

Comment: do i have to do anything on both servers before writing mysql_connect query ?

Comment: If both are on different shared hosts, then probably *no*, you won't be able to access the SQL server directly. And neither should you over the internet. You'll have to build a web service in front of the database to connect to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is it possible" is a bit over-reaching, I think. To give you the shortest answer, yes, it is **possible**. However, whether or not **you** could do it depends on a lot of variables, not least of which is whether your hosting providers allow it. For instance, I use Hostmonster for Linux hosting, and to remotely access my MySQL database I have to first whitelist the IP address of the machine that will be accessing it.

Most hosting services provide a F.A.Q. section that should do a decent job of answering this particular question for you. Some will even provide support technicians help you set it up (Hostmonster does, within reason).

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
 <?php
    // Server in the this format: <computer>\<instance name> or 
    // <server>,<port> when using a non default port number

    // Suppose your "www.abc.com" has an IP = 192.168.1.1
    // So to connect, do something like this : 

    $server = '192.168.1.1,PORT_NUMBER'; // FOR WINDOWS
    $server = '192.168.1.1:PORT_NUMBER'; // FOR LINUX

    // Connect to MSSQL
    $link = mssql_connect($server, [username], [password]);

    if (!$link) {
        die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: you have to write this configuration in "www.xyz.com" and you have to use the static IP of "www.abc.com", not the dynamic one..!!